# Check if webpage contains specific text

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, vbscript, autologin

I need a VBScript that cheking if there is a TEXT on a webpage. I had no problem with IE, but due to some circumstances I need to use FF/Chrome.

```
Dim page 
Dim ff
page = "myURL"
Set ff = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ff.ShellExecute "firefox.exe", page, "", "", 1
WScript.Sleep 3000
Dim login
Set login = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
login.SendKeys "{TAB}"
login.SendKeys ("login")
login.SendKeys "{TAB}"
login.SendKeys ("passwd")
login.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Set login = Nothing
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

Open → login → and then I need to get a popup message if page contains TEXT (logged in) or not. Using IE I got this, okay, but how exactly can I do the same for Firefox?

```
If InStr(IEapp.Document.body.innertext, "Test") Then
  WScript.Echo "1:ok"
Else
  WScript.Echo "0:down"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

With VBScript you can't. Firefox and Chrome don't support COM automation. You may be able to do it with something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), but I don't have experience with those.

Comment: Yes, I searched for a while before asking, but thought this is just my lack of expierence.